# One Celery beat, many workers?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, message-queue

I'd like to run a single `DatabaseScheduler`-backed `celerybeat` instance shared by multiple workers. Redis is the broker. Will only one worker receive a scheduled task, or will all workers receive a scheduled task? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should run a single instance of the celery beat scheduler and then when the time comes for it to schedule a task, it puts a message on a message broker queue (Redis in your case). The queue is "celery" by default, but can be configured per task or per task instance based on your code/settings.

When you start up one or more workers you can tell each one which queues to listen to if you want, but they will just listen for messages on the "celery" queue again by default. When a message is pushed to the queue, the first available worker will receive a push notification from the broker and execute it. The broker will ensure that a single task instance will only be pushed to one worker at a time.

By default, if that worker crashes while executing the task, then it will be lost. You can also change that behavior using the [CELERY_ACKS_LATE](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-acks-late) setting, which means if a worker crashes its current task will be reassigned to the next available worker.

Comment: Also good to add, CELERYY_ACKS_LATE can be configured per-task using `@app.task(acks_late=True)`